# Distance metric for graphs with identical nodes?

Tags: graph-theory, trees

I have several minimum spanning trees with the same $n$ labeled nodes (no spatial position). Because all graphs are MSTs, there are at least $n-1$ edges (with a weight).

A common method to compare two graphs would the graph edit distance, but I wanted to know if there is a better metric / distance function for this special type of graph?